# c# binance api открытие ордера

Tags: c#, api

Уже второй день ломаю голову, где-то замылился взгляд.
Пытаюсь открыть тестовый ордер на binance.
Вот код:

```
    internal class Credentials
    {
        [JsonProperty("symbol")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("side")]
        public string Side { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("timeInForce")]
        public string TimeInForce { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("quantity")]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("recvWindow")]
        public int RecvWindow { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
       
        
        
    }
    //открытие позиции
    public async void CreateOrder(string instrument_name, string side, string type, double price, double quantity)
    {

        string path = "/api/v3/order/test?";
        string timeInForce = "GTC";
        int recvWindow = 5000;
        string time = GetTimestamp();
        string sign = GetSign_binance("symbol=" + instrument_name + "&side=" + side + "&type=" + type + "&timeInForce=" + timeInForce + "&quantity=" + Convert.ToDecimal(quantity) + "&price=" + Convert.ToDecimal(price) + "&recvWindow=" + recvWindow + "&timestamp=" + time);
        string url = API_URL_binance + path + "symbol=" + instrument_name + "&side=" + side + "&type=" + type + "&timeInForce=" + timeInForce + "&quantity=" + Convert.ToDecimal(quantity).ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "&price=" + Convert.ToDecimal(price).ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "&recvWindow=" + recvWindow + "&timestamp=" + time + "&signature=" + sign;
        string r;

        var Payload = new Credentials
        {
            Symbol = instrument_name,
            Side = side,
            Type = type,
            Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(quantity),
            Price = Convert.ToDecimal(price),
            TimeInForce = timeInForce,
            RecvWindow = recvWindow,
            Timestamp = time
        };
        
        var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Payload);


        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        top.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate ()
        {
            top.AppendText(DateTime.Now + " " + stringPayload + "\r\n");
        });

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        using (var response = await client_binance.PostAsync(url, httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false))
            r = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        sw.Stop();

        top.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate ()
        {
            top.AppendText(DateTime.Now + " " + r + "\r\n");
            top.AppendText(DateTime.Now + " " + url + " Время запроса: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\r\n");
        });
    }
```

На выходе получаю ошибку:

```
{
    "code":-1104,
    "msg":"Not all sent parameters were read; read '9' parameter(s) but was sent '10'."
}
```

Соответственно отправляемый json

```
{
    "symbol":"BUSDUSDT",
    "side":"BUY",
    "type":"LIMIT",
    "timeInForce":"GTC",
    "quantity":10.1,
    "price":0.9994,
    "recvWindow":5000,
    "timestamp":"1639325197716"
}
```

И ссылка куда отправляю:

```
api3.binance.com/api/v3/order/test?symbol=BUSDUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=10.1&price=0.9994&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1639325197716&signature=307dc0dce20835f3a80e40f11406d446d9f20e5edfdf5300229ddd026bef6b8c
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Судя по тому, что удаётся нагуглить по этой ошибке, что-то не то у вас с параметрами. В том режиме, который вы используете, ожидается 9 параметров, а у вас их 10. Где эти 10 параметров я и сам не понимаю. Лучше спросите где-нибудь на профильных форумах, где этот `API` обсуждают

Comment: 1. Не генерируйте URL адрес таким топорным способом! В C# есть специальный для этого билдер, звать его `UriBuilder`, а так, как вам нужен лишь запрос, то вовсе, берете `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty)` и добавляете туда все параметры как в простой словарь, на выходе он даст сформированную строку! 2. Ваш костыльный метод формирования строки дает скорей всего не тот результат, который ожидается, гдет не экранирует значение из за чего на сервер идет 1 лишний параметр. 3. Сайт просит только 4 обязательных параметра, зачем вы отсылаете все доступные?

Comment: Также, почему вы отправляете JSON как `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (форму)? Ну и по коду немного, всякие `[JsonProperty("timestamp")]` - лишние, они нужны тогда, когда отличается название свойства в c# и JSON, все, регистр не является отличием для JSON.NET. Далее, `async void` - это очень плохо! Научитесь делать грамотные `Task` и используйте их. `API_URL_binance + path` - этот URL должен быть задан только раз, как `BaseAdress` у `HttpClient`.  `top.Invoke` - косяк, почитайте про  `IProgress`. Ну и также гляньте `HttpClientJsonExtensions`, очень поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, переписал через HttpUtility.ParseQueryString и все встало на свои места